# Using mpv ASCII output with w3m

Tags: video, w3m

mpv is a video player that can output ASCII video (like mplayer2 and vlc, but with colors). I would like to use it with w3m, within w3m or showing a link to open it in another window using mpv.

For now when I w3m in newsbeuter just tell me that it can't support media format and display an inline picture from the video.

Do you know how to open a link with an external application and how to make it automatic ? It would be really cool if it can be done inline.

Thank you